# How to generate numbers based on a pattern in python

Tags: regex, python-2.7

I have to generate integers based on a pattern.
For example, I have to generate all the numbers **that contain only 4's and 0's** and that start with one or more 4's and end with zero or more 0's
I want code in Python (2.7) only. I don't want to check the pattern. I want to generate numbers in the pattern

Comment: just generate a random number, add a `4` at the beginning.

Comment: Sorry for not being clear, check the edit @Kent

Comment: There are infinitely many numbers which satisfy that pattern -- how do you intend to generate all of them?

Comment: Specific to the question I am dealing with I need upto 30 digit numbers @JohnColeman

Comment: Do you want all 4s followed by all 0s or can 4s and 0s be interspersed? For example --- is 4404040 okay?

Comment: No @JohnColeman, I want all 4's followed by 0's

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work:

```
[int("4"*i + "0"*(n-i)) for n in range(0,31) for i in range(1,n+1)]
```

It generates 465 distinct integers:

```
4, 40, 44, 400, 440, ..., 444444444444444444444444444440, 444444444444444444444444444444
```

On Edit: A recursive approach works in the more general case:

```
def multiRepeats(chars,n,initial = True):
    strings = []
    if len(chars) == 0 or n == 0: return [""]
    c = chars[0]
    rest = chars[1:]
    base = 1 if initial else 0
    for i in range(base,n+1):
        head = c * i
        strings.extend([head + tail for tail in multiRepeats(rest,n-i,False)])
    return strings

def digitRepeats(digitString,n):
    return sorted([int(s) for s in multiRepeats(digitString,n)])
```

For example

```
>>> digitRepeats("420",4)
[4, 40, 42, 44, 400, 420, 422, 440, 442, 444, 4000, 4200, 4220, 4222, 4400, 4420, 4422, 4440, 4442, 4444]
```

To answer your original post, evaluate `digitRepeats("40",30)`

Comment: Perfecto. There is a small edit needed for my answer. @John Coleman is there any other way too. This is fine for two integers what if its with 3 or more integers. It becomes too complex

Comment: I gave a more general approach which I *guess* is what you are after. I agree with others that you should strive to be more clear about what you are trying to do.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer@John Coleman. I am initial stage of stack overflow. I need to know a lot about this community. Thanks for your suggestion too

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that your remark about 4s and 0s was just an example and you really want a generic solution to "generate integers based on a pattern" I would suggest the string from regex generator family of libraries. Here is one for python: https://github.com/asciimoo/exrex

As seen in the readme, for your example you can do:

```
import exrex
(int(n) for n in exrex.generate('4+0*'))
```

Comment: Thank you. Can I do this with python's inbuilt libraries?

Comment: Not if you want a generic solution. You would basically be implementing a subset of the library relevant only to numbers. The word 'pattern' is too broad.

Comment: Nice one. Didn't know about that library.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is way understated. There are infinite numbers in your pattern, so you cannot list them all. In order to show how your question should be improved I'll answer your question in a way that probably is not what you want, but satisfies the requirements.

Your pattern can be written as `4[40]*`. There are infinite numbers with the form `4+` which satisfies your pattern. Since you will never finish these numbers, a generator that outputs only those ones satisfies your condition (you cannot have *all* but you can have *many* numbers).

```
from itertools import count, islice
numbers = (int('4' * i) for i in count(1))

# get 10 numbers
print list(islice(numbers, 10))
# [4, 44, 444, 4444, 44444, 444444, 4444444, 44444444, 444444444, 4444444444]
```

*moral of the story: you should understand your problem before asking for a solution.*

Comment: moral: Sorry, you didn't get the question perfectly too.I asked for trailing 0's too. 4's should be followed by 0's

Comment: @sushant047: sorry, but it's not what is stated there: *end with zero or more 0's*. `zero or more` normally means `zero or more`.

Comment: what about more 0's. Your solution doesn't deal with that @enrico.bacis

Comment: @sushant047: It *deliberately* doesn't deal with that. Your first formulation did not contain the `upto 30 digit numbers` limit, so the instances derivable from the pattern were infinite. When enumerating infinite number without imposing an order, you can decide to just solve a part of the problem, since you'll never run out of numbers of the form `4+` and this form satisfies the requirements. My solution *may* deal with the `0's` *after* outputting all the `4+` ones (*after infinite = never*). My solution wanted to show a solution that exploited the understated formulation of the question.

Answer (score 0):

Generate all numbers that satisfy your pattern:

```
def mygen():
    i = 1
    while True:
        # turn to binary, skip '0b' then change 1s to 4s and
        # finally turn it back to int
        yield int(bin(i)[2:].replace('1','4'))
        i += 1
```

Since you basically have only two digits '4' and '0' you can use binary representation to get all possible outcomes.
**Note that this generator runs infitely!**
To get the first 100 numbers use it like this:

```
gen = mygen()
first100 = [next(gen) for _ in xrange(100)]
```

Comment: Your answer will have interspersed 0's. What I want is 4's followed by 0's @swenzel

Comment: @sushant047 Sorry, I answered before you made that clear in the comments. From your question itself it sounded differently. I'll leave my answer anyway...